# CNN-Regression insensitive to input data

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I'm currently training a CNN + regression model that does the following

input: $ \dim x = (L, 2), \text{where} \ x_i \in (-0.1, 0.1) $  
output: $\dim y = (M), \text{where} \ y_i \geq 0, y_{i-1} \leq y_i$

The basic architecture is (each step with ReLU activation) : 
input $\rightarrow$ CNN1(3x2) $\rightarrow$ maxpool(2x2) $\rightarrow$ CNN2(3x2) $\rightarrow$ maxpool(2x2) $\rightarrow$ flatten $\rightarrow$ hidden1 $\rightarrow$ hidden2 $\rightarrow$ M outputs

The issue is that the model is completely insensitive to the variations in the input data, i.e., regardless of the input value, the model would predict an output that is almost the average of all training outputs.

Here I'm plotting 10 random predictions on the test set data
[image: Plotting 10 random predicts on the test set data]

Looks to me that there is not enough distinction in the inputs for the model to recognize, or that the input simply looks like noise to the model. I've tried some rudimentary data augmentation techniques, exponentiating the differences, normalization, etc. to no avail.

The training data is generated by diagonalizing matrices parametrized by input values, and the lowest $M$ eigenvalues are the output values.

Since my background is not in the field, I would appreciate any advice and suggestions. Thanks in advance.